# How can I export a video from Adobe Animate (Flash) with a transparent/no background?

Tags: flash, animation, adobe-premiere

First off, I understand that this is not a programming question but it is related to a web development project I am working on so I figured I may as well try it here.

I am editing a video in Adobe Premiere Pro. In that video I would like to add some simple animations (for example, a circle drawing itself around a specific part of the video that I want to draw attention to). For those animations, I am using Adobe Animate (formerly Flash). However, I so far haven't found a way to export the animation without a background so that for example only the self-drawing circle is visible.

I know that this is possible when exporting a swf but I need the format to be mp4 so that I can properly use it in Premiere Pro (at least as far as I know that's the format I need to use).

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out how to accomplish this. It's in the Media Encoder export settings. Format needs to be set to QuickTime -> GoPro CineForm RGB 12-bit with alpha channel. In that format, only the animation itself without a background is visible in the Premiere Pro project.

Answer (score -1):

Create a lime-green (as in green screen) or other contrasting colored background in your animation. In Premiere Pro add a keying effect (like Ultra Key) to your clip. Open the "Effects Control" tab. Use the eyedropper to click on the background and voila, background is gone.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the selection tool and in the properties menu, there should be a color labeled with 'Stage'. Write at the top left #454545.